# Blob size is not equal to MediaRecorder's sample rate

Tags: javascript, mediadevices

I use MediaRecorder to record audio from web browser and send it to the server via socket.io:

```js
    var recorder;
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true video: false }).then(
        (stream) => {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "audio/webm" });
            recorder.ondataavailable = function(event) {
                console.log(event.data) // Blob {size: 6478, type: 'audio/webm;codecs=opus'}
                // blob size is 6478, but should be 48000
            }
        }
    );
    recorder.start(1000);
```

I set time slice of recording to 1000ms: recorder.start(1000); The device sample rate is 48000Hz. So every 1s I must send 48000 samples to the server.
But as I see, there are just ~6000 samples every second.
Could you please help with this problem and how to resolve it?